# How to decode serverVerificationData

Tags: android, ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, app-store

I'm working on IAP (in-app purchase) using [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) plugin and alla subscription are  auto-renewal subscriptions. In the Android implementation, get query past purchase from `InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition`.

Problem is in iOS: I must valid it before sending to server and I must decode it. Decoding by base64 return bytes. It is ASN1. I am trying to get to all previous transaction list from it by plugin asn1lib, but I failed.

Please help me with the code so I can use it in flutter; I have tried this code, but it's not working

```
 InAppPurchaseStoreKitPlatformAddition iosPlatformAddition =
              _inAppPurchase
                  .getPlatformAddition<InAppPurchaseStoreKitPlatformAddition>();
               await iosPlatformAddition.refreshPurchaseVerificationData().then((value){
                  storeReceipt = value!.serverVerificationData;
                });
              debugPrint("store data  $storeReceipt");
              Uint8List binaryData = base64.decode(storeReceipt);
              debugPrint("bin data $binaryData");
              ASN1Parser parser = ASN1Parser(binaryData);
              debugPrint("par $parser");
              ASN1Sequence sequence = parser.nextObject() as ASN1Sequence;
                debugPrint("seq $sequence");
                for (var item in sequence.elements) {
                  debugPrint("items is $
```

i want receipt data from app store  which is activate in device